# Mockito creating mock by reflection from the constructor parameter of a generic type

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to create a base abstract class for unit testing. It is very easy to do this in C# but couldn't in java. My idea is that I will have a TestFor class which is to be used as base for unit test. T represents the type under test. In this class I want to create the The object of type T with all its parameters of longest constructor MOCKED. That mean I have to reflect the class, get the longest constructor, pull out the parameters, create mock of this parameter and then create the object of type T. I have the following code but not working. Anyone who can try

```
public abstract class TestFor<T> {

protected Class<T> _class = null;
public HashMap<Class, Class<?>> _mocks = new HashMap<Class, Class<?>>();
protected T Target = null;

protected TestFor(Class<T> cls) {
    _class = cls;

    Constructor<T>[] allConstructors = (Constructor<T>[]) _class.getDeclaredConstructors();

    Constructor<T> ctorWithLongestParameter = null;
    int max = 0;
    for (Constructor ctor : allConstructors) {
        if (ctor.getParameterTypes().length > max) {
            ctorWithLongestParameter = ctor;
            max = ctor.getParameterTypes().length;
        }
    }

    final List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
    int i = 0;
    for (Class<?> p : ctorWithLongestParameter.getParameterTypes()) {
        Class<?> mock = Mockito.mock(p.getClass()); //This does not work
        _mocks.put(p.getClass(), mock);
        objects.add(mock);
    }
    try {
        Target = (T) ctorWithLongestParameter.newInstance(objects);
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public <E> E the(Class clss) {
    return (E) _mocks.get(clss);
}
```

}

Comment: What happens if you drop that extra `getClass()` call?

Comment: mock in Mockito cannot be applied to Parameter.....so no it does not work

Comment: What scenario are you trying to mitigate when you're running your tests?  It seems like this is doing several orders of magnitude more work than it ideally should be.

Comment: Because there are several floppy devleopers, I want to make sure an object undertest (Target) is always create with external dependancies mocked. so if I have a class Calculator to test  I will just   do CalculatorTest extends TestFor<Calculator> .... and at each test method , it ensures Target. is created with mocks. But anyway that is not the point, I want it to work.

Comment: The rationale *why* is very much the point; you're trying to work around some scenario (what is a "floppy developer"?  You mean "flaky"?) in a more prohibitive way than, say, enforcing good test coverage under penalty of termination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a several bugs in your code - logic, types, generics... Try this instead:

```
public abstract class TestFor<T> {

    protected Class<T> _class = null;
    public Map<Class, Object> _mocks = new HashMap<>();
    protected T Target = null;

    protected TestFor(Class<T> cls) {
        _class = cls;

        List<Constructor> allConstructors = Arrays.asList(_class.getDeclaredConstructors());
        Constructor ctorWithLongestParameter = Collections.max(allConstructors,
            (o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(o1.getParameterCount(), o2.getParameterCount()));

        List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        int i = 0;
        for (Class<?> type : ctorWithLongestParameter.getParameterTypes()) {
            Object mock = _mocks.get(type);
            if (mock == null) {
                mock = Mockito.mock(type);
                _mocks.put(type, mock);
            }
            objects.add(mock);
        }
        try {
            Target = _class.cast(ctorWithLongestParameter.newInstance(objects.toArray(new Object[objects.size()])));
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public <E> E the(Class<E> cls) {
        return cls.cast(_mocks.get(cls));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestFor<A> test = new TestFor<A>(A.class) {};
        System.out.println(test.Target);
        System.out.println(test.the(Object.class));
        System.out.println(test.the(Number.class));
    }

    public static class A {
        public A() {
            System.out.println("Empty constructor");
        }
        public A(Object o) {
            System.out.println("Constructor [o=" + o + ']');
        }
        public A(Object o, Number n) {
            System.out.println("Constructor [o=" + o + ", n=" + n + ']');
        }
    }
}
```

This code works with Java 8, however after small modifications it will work on the elder versions.

Comment: Thanks. I m learning Java and thank you for optimizing it sytatically